# Random edges that don't exist?

Tags: subdivision-surface

[image]

The seemingly random edges that are crisscrossing everywhere do not exist and can't be clicked on. If I click on the connecting vertices, the "edge" disappears. Any fix other than just ignoring them? Applying subdivision or solidify modifiers seems to make them go away but I have to work with those off for now.

Answer: When I press "Adjust edit cage to modifier result" twice it just fixed it.

Comment: Hey, could you upload your .blend-file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com? I'll have a closer look. 
My first guess would be duplicate vertices. try "remove doubles" in Edit mode

Comment: @bstnhnsl It says error uploading so I'll try again in awhile. I did try removing doubles which didn't remove any. Also interestingly enough they don't show up in edge or face select, only vertex select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain problem in this case might be different but if unnecessary geometry is only composed of edges you can subtract selection based on selection modes.
Deselect all, enter Edge selection mode, select all. Then enter Face selection mode. Selection will be edited accordingly as edges can't be selected in Face selection mode. Switch to Edge selection mode, invert selection, delete edges.

[image]

There are other ways to delete loose geometry, one way is to use *Select > Select All By Trait* and use options there.

Comment: I think I followed what you said correctly but for some reason the edges only appear in vertex select mode so this doesn't work?

Comment: @MarkRyan it is impossible to tell exactly what and why didn't work from several words description. Edges by definition can not appear only in Vertex selection mode without being selectable in Edge selection mode. You could upload the file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for more detailed diagnosis (pasteall.org if the first isn't working) or at the very least include more screenshots of what happens exactly when selecting them (file is better in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Remove Doubles in Edit mode should fix the issue.

Switch to Edge mode and Remove Doubles

Also switch to Vertex mode and Remove Doubles

And even Face mode

Comment: Viewing it in edge or face mode doesn't display the edges but switching back to vertex edit brings them back.

Comment: Then you can just ignore it if its not affecting render quality

Comment: Why would remove doubles fix this?